# Display data for current month

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the daily wages employee details from employee table for the current month.

For Eg: Month will be displayed as Current Date-1. 
(If current date is 18-JUN-2014, then data for the month will be displayed from 01-JUN-2014 to 17-JUN-2014. 
Similarly, if current date is 01-JUN-2014, then month data will be displayed from 01-MAY-2014 to 31-MAY-2014)

Please help me how to write the query for above requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should have something like:

**Table EMPLOYEE :**

```
| EMP_ID | NAME | ...
```

**Table EMPLOYEE_DETAIL :**

```
| WAGE_DATE | EMP_ID | AMOUNT | ...
```

So this should be like:

```
select D.EMP_ID, E.NAME, trunc(D.WAGE_DATE), sum(AMOUNT) WAGE_AMOUNT
from EMPLOYEE_DETAIL D
inner join EMPLOYEE E on (E.EMP_ID = D.EMP_ID)
where trunc(D.WAGE_DATE, 'MON') = trunc(sysdate, 'MON') -- Only on current month
group by D.EMP_ID, E.NAME, trunc(D.WAGE_DATE)
```

**EDIT :** If you want data from previous month, you can do:

```
where trunc(D.WAGE_DATE, 'MON') = trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MON')
```

instead. If you want to get data fro mprevious month only if 1st day of current month,you can do:

```
where trunc(D.WAGE_DATE, 'MON') = case when trunc(sysdate) = trunc(sysdate, 'MON')
                                       then trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MON')
                                       else trunc(sysdate, 'MON')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above query will compare month of sysdate and wagedate. Suppose, If sysdate is '1/6/2014' then it will check that there is a record matching for month june in wage_date and display. But i need the output like if sysdate is '1/6/2014' display data from 1/5/2014 to 31/5/2014.